# interfacing: simplified

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++, interface

i've been doing some research on interfaces and a simple layman's explanation for what it truly is. when searching through seas of books For some reason people love using overly complex explanations and jargon to explain truly simple concepts (guess it makes them feel big) and i have a gut feeling it's the same in this case.

so from what i could grasp, it seems like interfaces are nothing more than a way to reserve method names, their return type if any, and the type and amount of arguments they accept. so when a class implements an interface (or interfaces) it is forced to define the body of each method from the interface(s). Am i on the nose with this one or do i need to keep digging?

p.s. i know javascript doesn't have support for interfaces, but i still need to understand the concept because there are quite a few places where it's shown how to emulate to an extent.

Comment: Probably the most important aspect of interfaces is that the programmer can code in terms of interfaces. For example, a programmer can code her Q&A website, StackUnderflow, to parse user submitted content with a `Parser` interface without having to care if it's a `MarkdownParser`, `LatexParser`, `AsciidocParser`, etc. If she changes her mind about what format the content should be in, she can just switch out a single line of code. As long as the class she chooses implements the `Parser` interface, everything will work fine.

Comment: Aside ("makes them feel big"): whenever I fail to explain something because the explanation is overly complex, I feel smaller, not bigger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I explain the concept to lay people using an analogy that most people understand - plastic molding.

The interface defines the shape of an object in the exact same way a mold will provide the shape of the finished product.

You could inject a mold with White plastic, blue plastic, something exotic like an Epoxy or clay.

What matters is, no matter what they are actually made of, they all have the same exact consistent shape to the purchaser of the product.

For code, this means no matter what code is used to implement the interface, they all follow the same consistent contract/shape to the end user.

I hope that might help a little.

Edit -

To extend the analogy to Abstract classes, imagine the next step in the molding process. You run a White, blue, and red plastic production run, but then each item needs to be painted at a separate factory, we just ship them out.

The item is not finished, but it does have its shape defined. Someone later will come and fill out the details that our factory left blank.

These items cannot be sold until they get that last painting step.

In code, the abstract implementation of the interface provides some (or none) of the implementation, but leaves another descendant class to complete the contract, and in the same way no one can create an instance of the class until the contract has been completed.

In the same way though, you can still refer to an abstract class in code, just like you can refer to the unpainted mold item as a "White molded thing" wither or not it is painted!

**Edit 2**

Here's a short example

```
void Main()
{
    //IMold mold = new IMold(); // error - can't create instance of an interface
    //Fruit fruit = new Fruit(); // error - can't create instance of an abstract class

    Apple apple1 = new Apple(); // good
    Orange orange1 = new Orange(); // good

    Fruit apple2 = (Fruit)apple1; // good - Apples are fruit
    Fruit orange2 = (Fruit)orange1; // good - oranges are fruit

    IFruitMold apple3 = (IFruitMold)apple2; // good - Apples fit the Mold
    IFruitMold orange3 = (IFruitMold)orange2; // good - Oranges also fit the mold


    //now I can do this:
    //Notice that `fruits` is of type IList<T> but the new is List<T>
    //This is the exact concept we are talking about
    //IList<T> is some kind of set of items that can be added or subtracted from
    //but we don't have to care about the implementation details of *HOW* this is done
    IList<IFruitMold> fruits = new List<IFruitMold>();
    fruits.add(apple3);
    fruits.add(orange3);

    foreach( var fruit in fruits )
    {
        fruit.PlasticColor.Dump(); // ok I can read
        fruit.PlasticColor = ""; // error - no Set defined in the interface

        // depending on the **implementation details** of what type of fruit this is true or false
        // we don't care in the slightest, we just care that we have some IFruitMold instances
        fruit.RequiresPainting.Dump(); 
    }
}

interface IFruitMold
{
    string PlasticColor { get; }
    bool RequiresPainting { get; }
}

abstract class Fruit : IFruitMold
{
    private string m_PlasticColor = string.Empty;
    public string PlasticColor { get; private set; }
    public abstract bool RequiresPainting { get; }
}

//notice that we only define the abstract portion of the base class
//it defined PlasticColor for us already!
//the keyword `override` is required  - it is to make it clear that 
//this member is overriding a member from it's parent.
class Apple : Fruit
{
    public override bool RequiresPainting { get { return true; } }
}

class Orange : Fruit
{
    public override bool RequiresPainting { get { return false; } }
}
```

Comment: actually it does help. so basically you're pre-defining methods(there shape) but not there core(the code contained within). so long as the code in the body of the implemented method follows the blue print laid out for it(return type, amount and type of arguments, etc...), all should work fine.

Comment: @codewombat You got it. I have a project that can push data to an external webservice, a mssql2008 db, or an iseries db2 database. The details of how to read and write to these systems is very different, but because I have a simple read/write Interface that they all implement, the entire rest of the project just asks for a data provider and calls "Get" or "Update" and never has to care about the details. That's the real key to all of this - You are using interfaces to hide implementation details.

Comment: @codewombat I edited in a further analogy to cover abstract interface implementations.

Comment: so complete the contract the abstract class needs to define the methods that are not going to be use by the subclass and the subclass then defines the remainder?

Comment: @codewombat No problem, I enjoy the thought exercise. It's a tricky concept to get right, but once you understand the power and flexibility you enjoy from hiding details and coding against interfaces you'll find it hard to imagine any other way.

Answer (score 10):

> For some reason people love using overly complex explanations and jargon to explain truly simple concepts (guess it makes them feel big)

Consider eschewing the editorial comments that impute bad motives to people who are trying to help you. **That's a really bad way to try to get people to help you.**

> It seems like interfaces are nothing more than a way to reserve method names, their return type if any, and the type and number of arguments they require. So when a class implements an interface (or interfaces) it is forced to define the body of each method from the interface(s). Am i on the nose with this one or do i need to keep digging?

You are on the right track but you err in the details. In C#, for example, an implementing class is not *required* to provide a body. The method which corresponds to the interface method could, for example, be an abstract method in an abstract class, which would then not have a body. And in C# an interface can require members other than methods; properties, events and indexers, for example.

A more concise and typical way to express the idea that interfaces impose a *requirement* that a *type* supply *members* that match certain *signatures* is to say that **the interface represents a *contract* that must be *fulfilled* by its implementer**. But that might be too complex and jargonish for your gut to stomach.

Comment: "For some reason people love using overly complex explanations and jargon to explain truly simple concepts (guess it makes them feel big)" what i ment by that is when searching through seas of books i've found that interfaces aren't clearly explained nor is there a good example of its everyday/real world use.

Comment: "But that might be too complex and jargonish for your gut to stomach." that's ok, i think the answers everyone else gave suite my needs just fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a nutshell interfaces are there to declare and promise everyone else that a class will have certain methods.

This is good when you create generalized methods and function, where you want a more abstract design. All you want to know is that your function can receive an object that had methods A B and C.

Comment: A perfect example of the use of interfaces is the MouseListener.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Comment: @Perry Monschau excellent link. so in an interface do i have to use every method in the interface or am i free to choose which witch one to define?

Comment: You must implement all of the methods of the interface, otherwise you do not meet the requirements of that interface. When you attach an object that implements the `MouseListener` interface to a button, the button doesn't care what the object really is. It knows it can call `mouseClicked()`, `mouseEntered()`, etc. on the object, and that's all that matters.

Comment: However, you can implement the methods and leave them empty.

Comment: @codewombat If you do not wish to provide an implementation for all members of the interface, you should implement it in an abstract class, and define the implementations in it's descendants.

Answer (score 2):

Interface is just a simple empty class, that show the contract on how you real class should look. I think you have the concept ok.

They don't reserve anything (I don't understand what you mean by that), is just a way so when you build your class around the interface, you have a prior knowledge of how will your class look like. And also you can know before which methods will it have.

Comment: Or, in Java and C#, so that you can have a "type", with specific behaviors, without requiring that a class extend `MySpiffyBaseClass`.  Some stuff just shouldn't require wasting one's only superclass slot on.  Event listeners in Java, for example.

Answer (score 2):

> when a class implements an interface (or interfaces) it is forced to define the body of each method from the interface(s).

Yes.  Interfaces are contracts.  They let others know that your class implements certain functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I would say its more than reserving the method name it is a way of making a contract that the method will exist and the caller will not need to know what it does but it will still be available to be called

A good example would be a pen and pencil both can implement an Iwriter interface with a write method but whoever calls the write method doesn't need to know that one uses ink and one uses lead the caller will just know that it is going to write words on the paper.

Comment: so when calling the interface they just need to know what arguments it takes and what type of data it returns and they're left to define what it does?

Comment: that is correct. They don't need to worry at all about what is going on once it is called all that is needed is whats going in and whats coming out (if anything is returned)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces provide a uniform way of interaction with a set of objects.

No matter what the object is, if it implements the interface we know that it will respond to a method defined in the interface. In this way, we can create objects that represent different things in a project and still interact with them in the same way. The actual implementation of the methods defined in the interface can be completely different, but they will take the same inputs and provide the same type of output.

Answer (score 1):

Basically an interface is a contract which can define properties (getters and setters) or methods (with whatever parameters you require). If an object 'implements' the interface it needs to define a concrete implementation for ALL the properties and methods defined in the interface.

For unit testing or Inversion of Control containers interfaces really come into there own as you can call methods/properties on the interface without knowing anything about the object which actually implements it.

Answer (score 1):

Interface is used to provide common functionality among a set of completely unrelated objects.

Lets say we have a bunch of animal objects and we need to separate pets from that bunch. The task of separation becomes really simple if we enforce a contract such that all the animals which are pets needs to implement `IPet` interface.